# mysql - what does this error mean?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1452

I do not require this error to be solved. I just need to understand what it means so I can approach it myself.

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
  (`db`.`transaction`, CONSTRAINT `transaction_ibfk_2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`id`))

INSERT INTO `transaction` ( `client_id`, `cost`, `website_id`, `product_id`,
    `template_number`, `value`, `order_id` )
    VALUES ( '17', '', '2480', '', '', '12', '1');
```

What is a foreign key? How is it set?

What does `CONSTRAINT transaction_ibfk_2` mean?

Does this mean I need to have a table called `transaction_ibfk_2`?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you Google 'Foreign Key' and do some reading first.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting an empty string as `productid` (Fourth item in the list)

```
INSERT INTO transaction  
(client_id, cost, website_id, product_id, template_number, value, order_id) 
VALUES ('17', '', '2480', '', '', '12', '1')
```

There is a referential integrity constraint set up to ensure that you must only insert `productid`s matching one in the referenced `product` table.

Answer (score 0):

This means you are trying to add a value into the foreign key column which is not available in the referenced column or trying to add blank in foreign key column.
i.e. You are trying to add product_id as blank which is not allowed. All values in foreign key column must be valid values present in the main referenced column id.

Answer (score 0):

There's not necessarily a relationship between constraint names and tables although most people name them appropriately to make their lives easier.

All this means is that you have a `transaction_ibfk_2` constraint. The actual problem is in the rest of the message:

```
FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product  (id)
```

You need to insert a row into your `product` table first. The `id` that you insert there should be the `product_id` you're trying to insert into `transaction` (which is `''` for some reason - I'm pretty certain this should be a real value (or possibly NULL)).

You can create foreign keys with a clause of the [`create table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) or [`alter table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) DDL statements.